# Getting the value of a list item gives me 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all, I have this unordered list:

```
<ul class="carl">
    <li id='2' value='test'>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I can access it through jQuery by doing something like this:

```
alert($('.carl li')[0].id);
```

It works fine, the `id` is properly alerted, but if I do something like this:

```
alert($('.carl li')[0].value);
```

then I get `0` even though I have a value set on the element.

What causes this behavior?

Comment: it would probably make more sense to access those attributes using jquery's `attr` method: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Or the `val()` method: `$('.carl li').eq(0).val()`

Comment: lis really do not have a value. You should be using data attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already some correct answers, but I wanted to add a shorter and less verbose way of doing the same thing:

```
alert($('.carl li').eq(0).attr("value"));
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
alert($('.carl li').eq(0).attr("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="carl">
    <li id='2' value='test'>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ooooo i see so by doing that, i am still accessing them as jquery object?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta That is correct! If you use `eq(0)` you still have the jQuery object, whereas if you use `[0]` it gets unwrapped.

Comment: I still got `0` though

Comment: since li's don't actually have a defined `value` attribute that is apart of the spec try `alert($('.carl li').eq(0).attr("value"));` to grab the user defined attribute

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta Fixed and tested. This one works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `attr()` method for reading attributes:

`alert($('.carl li').eq(0).attr('value'));`

Comment: This doesn't work because i am accessing native dom.

Comment: you should remove the `[0]` from the code so the `attr` call is on the jQuery object and not the DOM node

Comment: Now that the `[0]` is removed, it's not clear which `li` the value attribute is being read from. Consider using `eq(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var valu = $('.carl li')[0];
alert($(valu).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` has no HTML5 attribute `value` as stated, do this: `alert($('.carl li').eq(0).text());`

But you could also do this for valid HTML5:

```js
console.log($('.carl li').eq(0).attr('data-value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="carl">
  <li id='2' data-value='test'>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```